# PostgreSQL execute a default query when no row are returned

Tags: postgresql, default-value

I need to calculate the average score of a **list of userId.**

I have a table `user_place_score`:

```
(user_id, place_id, score)
```

Sometimes I do not have the score (no row for `(user_id,place_id)` in the table) so I need to fetch a "default" score from the table `default_place_score`:

```
(place_id, score)
```

Is is possible in PostgreSQL to do this in one query? For a given list of users and *one* `place_id`, select all their scores in the `user_place_score` and if no row is found then take the score found if the `default_place_score` table?

Basically I want to avoid doing this kind of stuff:

```
for (Integer userId : userIds) {
  score = (query to fetch the score for this userId)
  if (score == null)
    defaultScore = (query to fetch the default score for this PlaceId)

  total = total + defaultScore
}

//return the average
return total/numberOfUser
```

Comment: If a user has no score, is there a row with `NULL` in score column? Or not? (you say *"not row found"*) If there is no row, how do you know a user's place_id?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough in my question.  When I say that I have no score this means that the row is not present "at all"  in the table

Comment: And you are interested in a specific `place_id`?

Comment: Yes the input are a list of useids and one placeid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemed you need a simple `LEFT JOIN` but with the added comments, it gets a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id,
    p.place_id,
    COALECSE(ups.score, d.score) AS score
FROM 
    user AS u
  CROSS JOIN                                          -- the places we are
    (VALUES (1),(2),(3),...,(10)) AS p (place_id)     -- interested in
  LEFT JOIN
    user_place_score AS ups
      ON  ups.user_id = u.user_id
      AND ups.place_id = p.place_id
  LEFT JOIN 
    default_place_score AS d
      ON d.place_id = p.place_id
WHERE                                         -- the users we are
    u.user_id IN (6, 28, 496, ...) ;          -- interested in
```

Comment: Thanks alot ypercube! Yes indeed it is more complex! I have just tried and it does perfectly what i was looking for! I know I didn't specify it in the question, but is possible to select the AVG when using COALECSE?

Comment: You can use `AVG(COALESCE(...))` of course, If you have for example `GROUP BY p.place_id` (and remove the user_id from the Select list)

Answer (score 1):

You could use COALESCE() .. it returns the first non-null value in the list passed to it..

`COALESCE((QUERY TO GET SCORE FOR USERID),(QUERY TO GET DEFAULT SCORE))`

*EDIT*

oh - you added "list" requirement ... see @ypercube's answer, then.

*EDIT2*

If the place_ids exist in a separate table, and they only DON'T EXIST in the table you're querying to get scores (which, imo, would be considered a 'good design decision'), then you should include that table in your query .. COALESCE() as used in @ypercube's answer should work fine in that case.

```
SELECT 
  u.user_id,
  u.place_id,
  COALECSE(u.score, d.score) AS score
FROM
  place_list AS pl
LEFT JOIN
  user_place_score AS u ON pl.place_id = u.place_id
LEFT JOIN 
  default_place_score AS d
    ON d.place_id = u.place_id ;
```

Above taken and edited from @ypercube's answer.

Comment: Yep, tried that already but how can I make it loop through a list of userId ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT
   user_place_score.user_id,
   user_place_score.place_id,
   COALESCE(user_place_score.score, default_place_score.score) AS score
FROM
   user_place_score
   LEFT OUTER JOIN default_place_score ON default_place_score.place_id = user_place_score.place_id
```

`COALESCE` function returns first no-NULL value from the given list, so if `score`from `user_place_score` is not NULL then the function peaks `user_place_score`.`score`, else it will take the value from `default_place_score.score`.